# How to prove that there is not a monomorphism from Klein 4-group to $Z_6$(or a epimorphism from $Z_6$ to $V_4$)?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism, monomorphisms

How to prove that there is not a monomorphism from  Klein 4-group to $Z_6$(or a epimorphism from $Z_6$ to $V_4$) ?

I know that:
If $f$ is a monomorphism than $Kernel(f)={0}$ .

In $V_4$ , three elements have order 2.

In $Z_6$ , $'3'$ has order 2, $'2'$ and $'4'$ have order 3 , $'1'$ and $'5'$ have order 6.

I read a theorem which says:"If $G$ and $G'$ are finite groups and $f$ is a homomorphism between them so that $f(a)=a'$ , where $a$ is from $G$ and $a'$ is from $G'$ , then the order of $a'$ divides the order of $a$."

My question is:Using this theorem, can I say that the monomorphism between $V_4$ and $Z_6$ does not exist since orders $3$ and $5$ do not divide $2$(order of all elements of Klein group)?

Comment: Use Lagrange's theorem. Neither of their orders divide each other.

Comment: So I can use this theorem to say that the epimorphism and the monomorphism  do not exist?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem directly implies that the monomorphism doesn't exist and with a little more work (possibly involving the first isomorphism theorem) indirectly implies that the epimorphism doesn't exist either. Also, what group theory text are you working from that uses "monomorphism" and "epimorphism"?

Comment: Advanced modern algebra-joseph rotman

Comment: Please vote for undelete https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954331/what-are-the-circles-preserved-by-an-inversion/3954335#3954335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively:

- $Z_6$ is cyclic and so all its subgroups are cyclic. Since $V_4$ is not cyclic, it cannot be embedded into $Z_6$.
- Every homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic. Since $V_4$ is not cyclic, it cannot be an homomorphic image of $Z_6$.

Comment: Would you explain the word "embedded" in some other words,please?

Comment: @Tota, "embedded" = "there is an injection (monomorphism) from it"

Comment: Couldn't we simply rule out such a monomorphism from any group of order $4$ (Klein's or not), based on Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: @user750041, yes, but I said "Alternatively". The comments to the question already handle the approach via Lagrange's Theorem